# Как изменять данные в игре или как работают читы?

Tags: алгоритм, reverse-engineering

Как я программно могу менять значения в другой программы\игры? ведь нет никакого изначального "api"... я подозреваю, что изменения происходят на низком уровне, то есть изменяются данные в памяти.. но как они тогда узнают адреса? и что именно этот адрес принадлежит именно этой программе\игре??

Comment: Что касается Windows, то советую почитать Рихтера - "Windows для профессионалов", в частности "Глава 22 - Внедрение DLL и перехват API-вызовов". Если коротко, то вы можете внедриться в память чужого приложения и выполнять код из его адресного пространства: [wiki: DLL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection). По Unix системам ничего сказать не могу.

Comment: Читайте про виртуальное адресное пространство. Давно уже в юзермоде нет проблемы попасть в "чужие" адреса.

Comment: "и что именно этот адрес принадлежит именно этой программе\игре??" - такого вопроса в ОС с виртуальной памятью не существует. Виртуальные адреса не могут "принадлежать именно этой программе\игре". Физические могут, но в данном вопросе это не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

*"я подозреваю, что изменения происходят на низком уровне"*

**Верно подозреваете:)** Но есть немного и другие штучки.

А так, давайте рассмотрим одну онлайн игру. Смысл такой, есть игроки тоесть танки. У танков есть определенное действие, например стрельба, передвижение.

Выходит: 1 программа сервер, которой мы отправляем данные, а она обрабатывает их. И неограниченное количество клиентов которые эти данные и шлют(перемещение танков).

В клиент программе присутствуют обычные нам **ограничения**. Например: вы можете выстрелить только 1 раз в 2 секунды. Тоесть пользователь нажал на пробел->проверка на таймер->если все ок то отправляем серверу комманду что мы выстрелили.

Вот пример небольшой игры. Как создать под нее чит? Требуется детально продебагить код программы, ее действия. Существуют множество утилит делающие это, они используя низкоуровневое апи могут определить какие программа вызывала функции, что писала в переменные.

И искать изьяны. Например: если клиент при нажатии на клавишу вперед отправляет напрямую кординаты нахождения танка, то почему-бы не отправить свои нужные кординаты:) Или если клиент отправляет с какой скоростью движется танк, определяя природные условия, то почемубы не отправить скорость нужную. Вот на таких недочетах и строятся читы.

Если игра оффлайн: дело становится проще, мы имеем лишь 1 прогу. Мы сможем также продебагить программу, продизасемблировать (тоесть разобрать прогу на исходный код) и установить нужные нам значения, например человек может подниматся по лестнице с такой-то нужной нам скоростью.